# Spreading in a `useEffect` casuing huge number of rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a sort handler defined like so:

```
  const onSortHandler = useCallback((property: string, direction: string) => {
    setTodoList([...todoList.sort(/**<sort function snipped>**/)]);
  }, [todoList]);
```

This function is passed down to a child component where I have something like:

```
  const [sort, setSort] = useState<{ name: string | undefined, direction: string | undefined }>({ name: 'id', direction: 'asc' })

  useEffect(() => {
    onSortHandler(sort.name, sort.direction);
  }, [sort, onSortHandler]);
```

The idea being that whenever someone changes the sort property and direction, I trigged a new sort and spreading the new object into `setTodoList` causes a rerender.

Now this works fine, but eslint told me that I should add `onSortHandler` to the `useEffect` dependencies array, which I did, and it caused a massive amount of renders, so I followed it's advice and added `useCallback` into the mix.

So I get a huge amount of renders, making the sort functionality not work. If I remove `onSortHandler` from the `useEffect` dependency array, it works fine but I'm getting the eslint warning I'd like to sort.

I know that it's the spread causing the issue as if I remove it, the issue goes away (but then the list never rerenders on a new sort which is another problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `onSortHandler` *stable* (meaning it never changes) like:

```
const onSortHandler = useCallback((property: string, direction: string) => {
  // use functional state update:
  setTodoList(current => current.slice().sort(/**<sort function snipped>**/));

}, []); // < no dependencies
```

This allows you to use it as a dependency wherever necessary without it actually triggering any update effects.

*Note*: I changed the spread to `slice` (make a copy first), because using `.sort` on `current` (or `todoList` in your code) is still a state manipulation, as `sort` sorts *in place*.

---

Ref: [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)